# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '01-4001' to data type int

Tags: sql-server

My stored procedure is as follows:

```
DECLARE @LOCATION_ID VARCHAR(MAX) = 3,  
        @INVENTORY_ITEM_ID VARCHAR(MAX) = '01-4001' ,
        @CALLFROM VARCHAR(MAX) = 'FRAMES' --Requested by VIkram Dated 29jan 2020 For MBT :- 25401,25402  

BEGIN  
    SET NOCOUNT ON;  

    BEGIN TRY  
        DECLARE @TABLE_LOCATION_ID TABLE    
                                   (  
                                       ID INT,   
                                       LOCATION_ID INT  
                                   )   

        INSERT INTO @TABLE_LOCATION_ID  
            SELECT * 
            FROM dbo.SPLIT(@LOCATION_ID, ',')  

        SELECT * FROM @TABLE_LOCATION_ID

        DECLARE @TABLE_INVENTORY_ITEM_ID TABLE    
                                         (  
                                             ID INT,   
                                             INVENTORY_ITEM_ID VARCHAR(MAX) -- 2189
                                         )   

        INSERT INTO @TABLE_INVENTORY_ITEM_ID  
            SELECT * 
            FROM dbo.SPLIT(@INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, ',')  

        SELECT * FROM @TABLE_INVENTORY_ITEM_ID  

        SELECT DISTINCT LOCATION_ID 
        FROM @TABLE_LOCATION_ID

        IF('FRAMES' = 'FRAMES')  
        BEGIN  
            --  declare @LOCATION_ID int ,
            --@INVENTORY_ITEM_ID  VARCHAR(MAX);
            SELECT DISTINCT   
                I.[UPC_ID],  
                I.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,  
                IP.LOCATION_ID,  
                PL.LOCATION_NAME,  
                F.MANUFACTURER,   
                (CASE WHEN F.BRAND IS NULL THEN '' ELSE F.BRAND END)  BRAND,  
                F.COLOR_NAME,  
                F.COLOR_TEMPLE,  
                F.[FRAME_TEMPLE],  
                F.FRAME_EYE_SIZE,  
                F.[FRAME_DBL],  
                F.[COLLECTION] ,  
                F.MODEL_NO ,  
                [DESCRIPTION],  
                IP.RETAIL_PRICE ,  
                IP.WHOLE_SALE AS WHOLE_SALE_PRICE  
            FROM 
                PMS_INVENTORY_ITEM_DETAILS I  
            INNER JOIN 
                PMS_INVENTORY_ITEM_PRICING_DETAILS IP ON I.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = IP.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID  
            INNER JOIN 
                PMS_FRAME_SPECIFICATIONS F ON I.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = F.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID  
            LEFT JOIN 
                PRACTICE_LOCATIONS PL ON PL.PRACTICE_LOCATION_ID = IP.LOCATION_ID  
            LEFT JOIN 
                [PMS_PURCHASE_ORDER_ITEMS] P ON P.UPC_ID = I.UPC_ID                          -- MBT#21084 Added by Trupti  
            LEFT JOIN 
                [PMS_PURCHASE_ORDERS] PO ON PO. PURCHASE_ORDER_ID = P.PURCHASE_ORDER_ID  
            WHERE   
                (IP.LOCATION_ID IN (3) OR  @LOCATION_ID IS NULL)  
                --AND (I.UPC_ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT INVENTORY_ITEM_ID FROM @TABLE_INVENTORY_ITEM_ID ) OR  @INVENTORY_ITEM_ID IS NULL)  
                AND ((I.UPC_ID IN ('01-4001') OR  @INVENTORY_ITEM_ID IS NULL)  
                      OR (PO.PO_NO IN (SELECT CAST(DATA AS INTEGER) 
                                       FROM dbo.SPLIT(@INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, ',')) OR @INVENTORY_ITEM_ID IS NULL))  
                AND (I.INVENTORY_CATEGORY = 'FRAMES')  
                AND (IP.IS_ACTIVE = 1)   
                AND (I.IS_ACTIVE = 1)   
            --ORDER BY   IP.LAST_SOLD_DATE  
            --OFFSET (@PAGE_NO - 1) * @PAGE_SIZE ROWS FETCH NEXT @PAGE_SIZE ROWS ONLY  
        END  
    END TRY   
    BEGIN CATCH   
        SELECT   
            ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,  
            ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;  
    END CATCH  
END
```

If I execute the above whole code then I the image below shows output with error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '01-4001' to data type int.

[image]

But if execute only select query then it works fine. with no error.

My datatype are `Varchar(max)`. Inventory_Item_id is = '01-4001'

If I put inventory_item_id as '2189' then whole execution doesn't throw error.

Response error in network like:

> ""error":true,"message":"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.\r\nParameter name: index""

In table `PMS_INVENTORY_ITEM_DETAILS` description `INVENTORY_ITEM_ID` is int length 4 and UPC_ID is `varchar` length -1.

Comment: [under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: I have removed it, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: What integer value are you hoping to get from the string "01-4001"? It's not an integer except maybe after removing the '-' !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Thanks for your help.

Issue is resolved
Changes made at line

```
OR (PO.PO_NO IN (SELECT CAST(DATA AS varchar) FROM DBO.SPLIT(@INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, ',')) OR @INVENTORY_ITEM_ID IS NULL))
```

`CAST(DATA AS INTEGER) updated with CAST(DATA AS varchar)` 
as parameter @INVENTORY_ITEM_ID is coming as '01-4001' [ - is there so error casting to int ]

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs here:

```
INSERT INTO @TABLE_INVENTORY_ITEM_ID  
SELECT * FROM  DBO.SPLIT(@INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, ',')
```

The separator you provide for your split function is `,` rather than `-` so the result will be `01-4001` again (rather than the expected `01` and `4001`), and converting that to an integer then fails.

To fix, use `-` as separator.

Comment: Thanks Henning but my id is '01-4001' this only.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but I've update my answer to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: my expected is '01-4001' this only and not 01 and 4001.  split by ',' is not a mistake
If more ids come then those will be like '01-4001,01-4002'

Comment: In that case, you are purposely trying to store `01-4001` as `ID`, and the conversion to int fails as `01-4001` is not a valid integer.

Comment: I got 1 point -- 
if I comment the line - 
OR (PO.PO_NO IN (SELECT CAST(DATA AS INTEGER) FROM DBO.SPLIT(@INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, ',')) OR @INVENTORY_ITEM_ID IS NULL))  

then it is working fine.
So issue should be in this line.

Comment: That line has exactly the same issue - you are trying to convert `01-4001` to int as well. As a minimal working example, try this: `select cast('01-4001' as int)`.